# Error ORA-00933 al guardar varios registros de una tabla java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Error ORA-00933 SQL command not porperly ended
Estoy intentando guardar varios registros al mismo tiempo desde una tabla en java pero al intentar guardar me genera este error SQL
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos de mi tabla son los siguientes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public void GuardarPrecios() {
    Connection cnn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        cnn = cn.getConexion();
       
    DefaultTableModel modelo=prdDP.getTablaPrecios();
    String pre="";
    
    int p=modelo.getRowCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        {
          pre+="INSERT INTO SPU_PRECIOS(TPR_ID,PROD_PORCENTAJEGN, PROD_COSTO_GANANCIA, PROD_IVA, PROD_PVP) VALUES ('"+modelo.getValueAt(i,0)+"',"+modelo.getValueAt(i,1)+","+modelo.getValueAt(i,2)+","+modelo.getValueAt(i,3)+","+modelo.getValueAt(i, 4)+")";  
        }
        PreparedStatement pst=cnn.prepareStatement(pre);     
        pst.execute();
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Tipos de precios se guardo correctamente");
        
    } catch (SQLException err) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error ! no no se puedo ejecutar la accion Solicitada \n Guardar Tipos Precios: "+ err.getMessage(), "Informacion", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, fatal);
        
    } 
    
}   

Error ORA-00933
```

Comment: El error aparentemente esta en esta línea  pre+= ya que si le quito el signo + el registro se guarda pero solo se guarda la primera columna y la otra no

Comment: 1. ¿Se guarda la primera _columna_ o la primera _fila_? 2. ¡Utiliza correctamente las sentencias preparadas! No concatenes tus variables, fijate en la sintaxis de "?" en la [documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). 3. ¿Te das cuenta que con cada `for`, estás incrementando la cantidad de `INSERT`? Estás concatenando una y otra vez tu consulta. ¡Depura tu código, siempre!

Comment: Se guarda únicamente la primera Fila